# How do I use CROSH to send and receive messages? Is it even possible?

Tags: terminal, messaging, chromebook, crosh

so recently I have seen many pictures on people using a terminal to chat [Chatting using Linux terminals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZ5YT.png) on Linux and Windows(Pro and enterprise) I am wondering how to do it the same way but in my school's Chromebook's CROSH. But why?

This is because my friend and I have got separated but still in the same class but I have to avoid going and talking to him (to stop creating disturbance) and they have blocked the google chat so I can't fix that. This is my only option.

Answer (score 0):

That picture is running the write command in a Linux terminal.
The write command is not available in crosh.

[image]